# MVC : How to bind serailsed object return from controller to dropdown using knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and knockout. Please refer the below code

Controller Code:

```
public string getJSON()
    {
        Product _objProduct = new Product();
        DataTable _objDT = _objProduct.getProduct();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = 
        new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in _objDT.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in _objDT.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

View Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divheader').append("<h2>Please place an order</h2>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Order/getJSON",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {

            function ReservationsViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.product = data;

                self.addOrder = function () {
                    alert('in');
                    self.order.push(new orderReservation());
                }
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
        }
    });
});
```

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Quantity/Unit</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Quanitity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="ddlProduct"></select>
        </td>
        <td><label></label></td>
        <td><label></label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried following:
`<select id="ddlProduct" data-bind="options: ProductName"></select>`
and my data contains in following format

```
[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":Monitor},......]
```

It gives error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: [object Error]; Bindings value: options: ProductName

Any Idea, where I'm going wrong??

Can anyone tell me how can i bind the data returned by ajax call to the ddlProduct using knockout.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your server side script returns valid JSON of the form:

```
[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":Monitor},......]
```

you could use the [`options binding`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) on your dropdown:

```
<select id="ddlProduct" data-bind="options: products, optionsValue: 'ProductID', optionsText: 'ProductName'"></select>
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetJSON", "Order")',
            success: function (data) {
                ko.applyBindings({ products: data });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also your controller action seems like a hell of a mess. I would try to improve it a little:

```
public ActionResult GetJSON()
{
    var products = new Product()
        .getProduct()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(row => new
        {
            ProductId = row.Field<int>("ProductId"),
            ProductName = row.Field<string>("ProductName")
        })
        .ToList();
    return Json(products);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for help dear. but i know what was wrong in my controller code?? why we need to use Json()??

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to `ReservationsViewModel`, which doesn't have `ProductName`.  It has `product`, which seems to actually be an array of products.  This seems to be what you want to bind your options to (an array).

Take a look at example 3 in [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).  You're binding to a list of objects, so you need to use a combination of options and optionsText to say that the name property is ProductName.

So something like this: `data-bind="options: product, optionsText: 'ProductName'"`